# Zoom with camera using touch and limit it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am moving my camera to mouse pointer location using mouse scroll wheel. But I want to do the same using touch and would like to limit the camera zoom in/out. How do I make my code better for this? Can someone help me with this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZoomOnPointer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera camera;
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") != 0) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 desiredPosition;

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                desiredPosition = hit.point;
            } else {
                desiredPosition = transform.position;
            }
            float distance = Vector3.Distance (desiredPosition, transform.position);
            Vector3 direction = Vector3.Normalize (desiredPosition - transform.position) * (distance * Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel"));

            transform.position += direction;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say  to limit your zoom is to stop the code whenever max zoom is reach so surround it with something like this:

```
    if (Distance < MaxDistance)
{
//scrollout code here
}
```

Comment: already tried, does not work.

Comment: You're going to need a case for when Distance > MaxDistance. In which case you set Distance to be equal to MaxDistance.